# How to hide datepicker when radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

So,
I have datepicker and a radio button. I want to hide the datepicker when the radiobutton is selected.

so this is the datepicker:

```
     <div formGroupName="groupDateTwo">
            <mat-form-field class="search-field-input md-datepicker-input-container">
              <input
                matInput
                readonly
                required
                [matDatepicker]="picker2"
                placeholder="start datum"
                formControlName="startDate"
                (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
              />
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

and this is when the radio button is selected:

```
if (optionLabel === 'Registratie') {   


    }
```

and this is the datefield:

```
startDate: Date;
```

So my question is, can you hide the datepicker when the radio button is selected in ts script?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use ngIf ?

Comment: can you show me what you mean?

Comment: when you check the radio button i guess you change optionLabel, right ? <mat-form-field *ngIf="optionLabel !== 'Regisratie'"

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter by mistake. I edited my comment.

Comment: why you want to do in .ts? if you are using ReactiveForm, in the .html you can use `<div *ngIf="myForm.get('nameOfradioButton').value!='valorToHide'" formGroupName="groupDateTwo" ...>`. In general, if only want to show/hide certains elements you needn't use .ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one new data-bound property on just above the constructor of your component or class like

```
showDatePicker: boolean = true;
```

And in your radio button selection hook, assign `true` to the above data-bound property.

```
if (optionLabel === 'Registratie') {   
   this.showDatePicker = false;
}
```

And finally in your component html, use `*ngIf="expression"` or `[hidden]="expression"`

```
<mat-form-field class="search-field-input md-datepicker-input-container" *ngIf="showDatePicker">
  ...
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it has to hide. so this.showDatePicker = false; isnt'?

Comment: Ok then reverse the condition... let me update my answer

Comment: not use a function + a variable + code for this, is innecesary, put in the .html

Comment: Thank you all. I solved. And I had to make a decision which ans ware was fitting the best

Comment: @Eliseo, Yeah you're correct here, but I tried to provide solution as op want... but anyways thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="optionLabel=='Registratie'">
 <mat-form-field class="search-field-input md-datepicker-input-container">
          <input
            matInput
            readonly
            required
            [matDatepicker]="picker2"
            placeholder="start datum"
            formControlName="startDate"
            (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
          />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

this means if optionLabel=='Registratie' then it will display the datepicker

Comment: OP doesn't mention that `optionLablel` is an data-bound property so i think we don't use in html

Comment: well, you are right, but as that bit of code is not present we are just guessing :)